# processing of annotations inside a method body

Tags: java, annotations, apt, annotation-processing

I am processing java annotations using the Pluggable Annotation Processing API. Is it somehow possible to also process annotations used **inside** a method body?

thanks for help. Peter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, i found the solution. As i thought, it is not possible with the current javac. local annotations are just simple comments and wont be processed by the pluggable annotation processing api. BUT there are interesting efforts in [JSR308](https://checkerframework.org/jsr308/), handling type annotations that support marvelous things as parameters on type-variables, local variables, annotated-type-checking and casting... and as it looks, it will be incorporated into openJDK 8. nice

Comment: JSR 308 does not directly support annotation processing (though it does correct a long-standing bug in which local variable annotations were not stored in the classfile).  It does have the other features you mention, and it is part of Java 8.  The [Checker Framework](http://checkerframework.org) is built on JSR 308 and does provide convenient visitors that process annotations within method bodies.

Answer (score 1):

In JSR269, the relevant interface would be [`javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/VariableElement.html), which inherits [`getAnnotation(Class<A> annotationType)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/Element.html#getAnnotation%28java.lang.Class%29) for accessing such annotations:

```
for (VariableElement variable : ElementFilter.fieldsIn(methods)) {
    final AnnotationType annotation = variable.getAnnotation(AnnotationType.class);
    if (annotation != null) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for that answer. But `methods` is a set of elements meaning, it should already contain the annotated fields (which makes method a bad name for that set). so `fieldsIn` does not return "fields (= local variables) in a method" but just filter a set of given elements. And the problem with that is, that the API wont give me annotated local variables (as parameter of the `process`-method). For now, it looks like i have to process ALL (not just annotated) classes and search for local-variable-annotations manually (though i dont know how exactly). or is there a way to use your example?